# Finding Conditional Moments in a Markov Process

Tags: matlab, performance, simulation, probability, markov-chains

This question combines math and programming. I will first describe the general problem and then give an example that is (hopefully) simpler to understand.

**General Question:** Consider a Markov-chain process of N-states with transition matrix Π. Each state is associated with a value x_n (n in {1,…,n}). Our goal is to find the unconditional average of the first two moments (mean and var) along T-period paths conditional on (i) the path starts in a subset of states, N_0, (ii) it ends in a subset of states, N_T, and (iii) it is not going through a subset of states, N_not, in any of the periods between 1 to T-1. By saying we are interested in the *unconditional average* of these two moments, I basically mean what would be the average of these two moments in the stationary distribution. To be more concrete, let me illustrate the goal of the exercise in a simple case.

**Simple Example:** Consider a 3-state Markov-chain process with transition matrix Π, and let the three state be denoted by A, B, and C. Each of these states are associated with some value (x_A, x_B, and x_C), respectively. We are interested in what happens along paths that satisfy the following condition. The path starts at point A, after 3 periods are in either points B or C, and between periods 1 to 3 never go again through point A. Denote this condition by (#). So, for example, a path which we are interested in would be {A,B,B,C} with the associated values {x_A, x_B, x_B, x_C}. We are interested in the average and standard deviation along such paths. In particular, we would like to find the unconditional average of these first two moments in paths that satisfy (#).

Let me now propose a solution based on simulating the process. Since both T and N are quite large, this solution is too slow for my  purpose.

**Simulation Solution:** Starting from some initial point simulate the process for a very long time period, and drop the first τ periods. Extract all paths along the simulation that satisfy condition (#) and compute the mean and std along each of these paths. Finally, simply take the average across these paths.

I’m hoping there is a better and more efficient way to achieve the goal. Since I want the solution to be accurate and the size of T and N the simulation takes a long time.

I would love to hear your thoughts and if you know of efficient methods to achieve this goal. Please let me know if something is not clear and I'll try to clarify it.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I know how to do this if `N_0` consists of one state, let's call that state `A`.

The long run probability of being in `A` is `pi(A)` and can be obtained by solving `pi = pi*P`, with `P` the transition matrix.

The other thing you need to calculate is the probability of those transient paths. You probably need to introduce a modified `P`, where all states `i` in the set `N_not` are absorbing (i.e. `P[i,i]=1` and `P[i,j]=0` for `j` is not `i`). Then starting from a vector `p(0)` which has a 1 in the element corresponding to state `A` and 0 otherwise, you can keep calculating `p(n) = p(n-1)*P` to get the probabilities of your transient paths.

Multiply the result of that by `pi(A)` to get the unconditional probability.

You can probably do something like this as well when `N_0` is a set, but I don't know how you should select `p(0)` in that case.